# How to make async rest call from a synchronous APIGEE Integration?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, integration, apigee

I have a requirement to make an async rest call from my APIGEE Integration even if the integration is called synchronously from my proxy. Is it even possible?

I am not able to find any option in the integration to make a async call in the rest task. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the best solution that I have found for this is to shift the part of the integration that you want to run asynchronously i.e. rest call in this case to a new Integration and make an asynchronous Integration callout from the current Integration. This can be done by changing the Execution startegy to async.

[image]